# Window CE 4.2 - Enumerating through the controls of a different running process

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have been charged with the task to send data from COM 1 to COM 2 in Windows CE 4.2. A running application takes data from COM 1 and displays it to the user in a form (textbox I assume). I then have to take that data and send it out COM 2. COM 1 is being used by the program displaying the data and I know of no way to hijack COM 1.

I figure trying to do a screen scrap would be the next step. Unfortunately this is compact framework and  an old version at that and from a lot of research it seems managed code is out of the question . Many of the API functions I would use are not available; FindWindowEx for example.

Here is where I am at now. I have created two projects. One runs with a TextBox and some wording. A separate application runs and tries to read the text in that TextBox. I have been able to find the running process based off the name of the form using FindWindow API. Using code I have found on this site I have even been able to enumerate through the controls of the form. However my TextBox is never found and many of the controls that are found where never placed on the form by myself (listbox, button). I assume those are the form's initial controls.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Currently this is in C# but VB or Visual C++ will be fine. Even if you have any ideas on a third party application. BTW I am not given the option to upgrade to a higher version of compact framework.

Thank you.

An update I just found out about. It does not look like I only screen scrape only new data but instead have to screen scrape the entire screen and send it out COM2. Someone will scan a barcode and I will send out all screen data through COM2. The data may include a picture etc.

Comment: Does the existing application that is currently using COM1 offer the ability to configure it to utilize a different COM port, or is it hard-coded to COM1?

Comment: TE2000 does offer the ability to change COM ports but in this case it is a hardware requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For a native C application I have one sceleton that enumerates all child windows and controls inside a dialog: http://code.google.com/p/rdp-auto-login/source/browse/trunk/rdp-auto-login/tscDialog.cpp. See ScanTSCWindow and the results found in the comment "TSC dialog elements".

I started with remote spy and looked thru the RDM window to find the CtrlID values. There is also a nice tool called zDump (http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/06/11/zdump-take-a-look-inside-windows-ce/) that runs on device and enables you to look at window elements.

The theory is that every element in Windows (either Mobile or desktop) is a window. Windows are accesible by there window handle. The handle is assign by the OS during CreateWindow/Ex. Inside dialogs, elements can be identified by there control ID (a resource value), the window class (ie "EDIT", "LISTBOX") and window text and internally by the window handle at creation.

The problem with Compact Framework apps is that they hide many of these basics and dialog (Form) elements can not be easily identified from another process.

As you say you are not able to capture COM1, what is, if you stop the application and then open COM1? As knonw, normally on one application can access a serial port at the same time. You can then read the serial data directly and do not need to access a foreign window.
There are also drivers that enable port mirroring or multiple access. Even for Windows CE based OS (ie http://www.virtual-serial-port.org/products/serial-splitter-mobile/).

If the application is a compact framework one you can take a look inside the code using .Net Reflector or similar .Net decompilers. I use that often to mimik or learn from other apps.

You say "I have been charged with the task to send data from COM 1 to COM 2 in Windows CE 4.2. A running application takes data from COM 1 and displays it to the user in a form (textbox I assume). I then have to take that data and send it out COM 2. COM 1 is being used by the program displaying the data and I know of no way to hijack COM 1." and if you do not start the other app you can write your own and do not need to parse the foreign app.

Possibly you can post the other app or more details of what it does what you can not do.

EDIT/UPDATE:

as we now know it is Intermec TE2000 (terminal emulation) the answer is to use the XMLRPC interface provided by TE2000. The interface is able to call back a function hosted by an xmlrpc server and send all screen content (text, fields and attributes) on screen changes. I have working c++ stl windowsce code for that.
If the device is connected via network, the xmlrpc server can even run on a PC.

As TE2000 does use native drwastring API you will not success in reading texts from the window. If you screen capture the window, you will have to do OCR on the image. XMLRPC does avoid all this.

**UPDATE2**:

I finished a class lib to get async screen updates using TE2000 xmlrpc: see https://github.com/hjgode/ITE_xml_rpc/tree/master/XmlRpcCS/XmlRpcCF
and http://community.intermec.com/t5/Thin-Client-Based-Development/Printing-CV60-Screen-Windows-CE-4-2/m-p/28663/highlight/false#M473

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Josef. I will look into everything you mentioned.

Comment: I will not have control over the program (Terminal Emulator) that is using COM1 and it must be running at all times. The serial splitter definitely would be the way to go if it works the way I hope it does.

I created two applications just for testing purposes to see if I could even enumerate through the controls with the old compact framework. In the final product I have to either read COM 1 with Terminal emulator while it is running (and using COM 1) or screen scrape it for any new data and send it out COM 2.

Comment: Is the terminal emulator written in .NET? If so use a reflector app to look inside. If it is a native app and a real Terminal Emulator, you may have no chance to find a control for the field. A TE application normally just displays text and does not use any windows controls. - Can you publish a screenshot? or name the TE application?

Comment: Sorry for the late response josef. It is Intermec's TE2000-5250 emulator. I do not believe it was coded in .NET. Here is the actual line of code I use to capture the process:

IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("fwpcv6h0", null);

Sorry I do not have a screenshot of the application.

Comment: OK, I know that app. It is written in C/C++. I will take a look at the application window and if one can read it from an external process.

Comment: Josef I am very appreciative of your time. Thank you for spending your time on helping me solve this.

Comment: I received an email from someone from who I believe actually helped develop the emulation software. He said that there are no child windows and that the text is drawn to the main window.

Comment: What device are you using and what is the version of TE2000? At some version TE2000 implements xml rpc and one can read the screen of TE2000 using xml rpc. I am currently searching for information on that. The doc is not that helpfull as it does not mention the port and location to use for the xml rpc requests.

Comment: I have not heard back yet but port 23 rings a bell. The device being used is an Intermec CV60 with CE 4.2.
http://www.intermec.com/products/cmptrcv60/index.aspx

Comment: Port 23 rings a bell? Do not understand what you mean. In appendix B of the manual "Intermec Terminal Emulator (ITE) Programmer's Reference Manual (23 Jun 2010)" at http://www.intermec.com/support/manuals/listing.aspx you find the xmlrpc interface of ITE. It seems to be using the sourceforge xmlrpc++ library: http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/. I will try to use that and see what I get. BTW: ITE xmlrpc uses port 50023.

Comment: Wow did I read your previous response wrong. Yes I do understand what you mean and you are of course right. I am currently reading through this document https://www.manualowl.com/m/Intermec/CV30/Manual/413725?page=1

Comment: Best is to use the IP address (or 127.0.0.1) of the device and port 50023 to call xmlrpc functions of TE2000. You can then do whatever you want with the returned screen text data. Please contact me or leave a question at community.intermec.com